# WHERE condition based on arrays in typeorm

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Having a given array with no maximum items such as:

```
["DEFAULT", "NEW"], ["REVIEW", "OPEN"], ["DEFAULT", "IN PROGRESS"]
```

How can I generate a query using typeorm such as

```sql
WHERE (tsk.category = DEFAULT AND tsk.status = NEW) OR (tsk.category = REVIEW AND tsk.status = OPEN) OR (tsk.category = DEFAULT and tsk.status = "IN PROGRESS")
```

In an elegant way ? Could I do something like `query.andWhere(query.orWhere())`

My code so far:

```js
const categories = await categoryService.getAllCategories();
const statusMap = [];
for (const category of categories) {
    for (const state of category.states) {
        const key = Object.keys(state)[0];
        if (state[key].metaState === filter.meta_status) {
           statusMap.push([category.name, key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that should work (`CategoryEntity` is the *class* entity):

```js
const categories: CategoryEntity[] = await getManager()
      .createQueryBuilder(CategoryEntity, 'tsk')
      .where(new Brackets((qb) => qb.where('tsk.category = DEFAULT').andWhere('tsk.status = NEW')))
      .orWhere(new Brackets((qb) => qb.where('tsk.category = REVIEW').andWhere('tsk.status = OPEN')))
      .orWhere(new Brackets((qb) => qb.where('tsk.category = DEFAULT').andWhere('tsk.status = "IN PROGRESS"')))
      .getMany();
```

For more information about *Query Builder* with `WHERE` clause see [this](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/adding-where-expression).